How to use BM25Retriever for large no of chunks?
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
vectorstore_retreiver = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3})

keyword_retriever = BM25Retriever.from_documents(list_of_doc)
keyword_retriever.k =  3
ensemble_retriever = EnsembleRetriever(retrievers=[vectorstore_retreiver,keyword_retriever],weights=[0.5, 0.5])

Above is the code for my hybrid search. It's working fine if my I have 100 or 1000 documents. But right now I am working on a project where I have more than 5 million chunks are there. How can I use bm25 retrival on these no of chunks. Is there any efficient way to load such large no of chunks?
I tried using loading everything in batches but could not found how to that?
